# Jest & React testing library: how to access element for getAllByText()

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

I try to write a unit test for a date picker component of my application. I don't know how to access to start day and end day elements inside getAllByText() for DateRangePicker.

*Here is the date picker component*

```js
export const DatePicker = (props) => (
  <Stack direction="row" spacing="2">
    <Field
      name={props.datePickerName + 'Day'}
      label={<Trans id="whenDidItStart.startDay" />}
      component={TextInput}
      //group={props.group}
      w={70}
      maxLength="2"
    />
    <Field
      name={props.datePickerName + 'Month'}
      label={<Trans id="whenDidItStart.startMonth" />}
      component={TextInput}
      //group={props.group}
      w={70}
      maxLength="2"
    />
    <Field
      name={props.datePickerName + 'Year'}
      label={<Trans id="whenDidItStart.startYear" />}
      component={TextInput}
      //group={props.group}
      w={110}
      maxLength="4"
    />
  </Stack>
)
export const SingleDatePicker = (props) => {
  return (
    <Stack spacing={4} pb="5">
      <Field
        name={props.name}
        datePickerName={props.datePickerName}
        group={props.group}
        label={props.label}
        helperText={props.helperText}
        component={DatePicker}
      />
    </Stack>
  )
}
export const DateRangePicker = (props) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <SingleDatePicker
        name={props.name + 'Start'}
        datePickerName="start"
        group={props.group}
        label={props.startLabel}
        helperText={props.helperText}
      />
      <SingleDatePicker
        name={props.name + 'End'}
        datePickerName="end"
        group={props.group}
        label={props.endLabel}
        helperText={props.helperText}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

*Here is the unit test*

```js
describe('<DatePicker />', () => {
  afterEach(cleanup)
  it('properly renders DatePicker components', () => {
    const submitMock = jest.fn()
    const { getAllByText, getByRole } = render(
      <I18nProvider i18n={i18n}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={canada}>
          <Form
            initialValues=""
            onSubmit={submitMock}
            render={() => <DatePicker datePickerName="test" />}
          />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </I18nProvider>,
    )

    screen.debug()
    const testDay = getAllByText(/whenDidItStart.startDay/)
    expect(testDay).toHaveLength(1)

    const testMonth = getAllByText(/whenDidItStart.startMonth/)
    expect(testMonth).toHaveLength(1)

    const testYear = getAllByText(/whenDidItStart.startYear/)
    expect(testYear).toHaveLength(1)
  })
  it('properly renders DateRangePicker components', () => {
    const submitMock = jest.fn()
    const { getAllByText, getByRole } = render(
      <I18nProvider i18n={i18n}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={canada}>
          <Form
            initialValues=""
            onSubmit={submitMock}
            render={() => <DateRangePicker label="dateRangePickerTest" name="dateRangePickerTest" />}
          />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </I18nProvider>,

    )
    const testStartDate = getAllByText(/***start day****/)
    expect(testStartDate).toHaveLength(1)

    const testEndDate = getAllByText(/***end day***/)
    expect(testEndDate).toHaveLength(1)
  })
})
```

I have tried getAllByText(/dateRangePickerTest.start/) and

```js
getAllByText(/dateRangePickerTest.end/)
```

but jest gives error: >Unable to find an element with the text: `/dateRangePickerTest.start/`.

Comment: check with screen.debug() to see what's in the DOM and what you can query for